# ImmutableJS Record merge

Tags: javascript, merge, record, immutable.js

I have imported an immutable record and wanted to add a new property to that before using it as the default state for my application. However, I cannot add the property at all despite trying `merge`, `mergeDeep`, `mergeWith` and `mergeDeepWith`. It returns the calling Record in all instances. I decided to try `merge` after seeing [this link](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/issues/1307).

The below code snippet simulates my problem

```js
a = Immutable.Record({a:1, b:2})
b = a()

c = Immutable.Record({z:12})
d = c()


e = b.merge(d)

console.log(e.toJS())

e = b.mergeDeep(d)

console.log(e.toJS())

e = b.mergeWith(d)

console.log(e.toJS())

e = b.mergeDeepWith(d)

console.log(e.toJS())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.js"></script>
```

This does not work with `v3.8.2` and even with `v4.0.0-rc-9`, in all cases, `b` is returned. I am looking for a solution using `3.8.2` itself not necessarily with `merge`

Not really experienced with immutable, so any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to be clear: You want a new Record with `{a:1, b:2, z:12}`?

Comment: @DominicTobias yes

Answer (score 1):

Maps are an approximation of key-value objects so use those instead of Records which have a different paradigm of Factories "A record is similar to a JS object, but enforces a specific set of allowed string keys, and has default values.".

```js
const a = Immutable.Map({ a: 1, b: 2 }); // or Immutable.fromJS({ ... })
const b = Immutable.Map({ z:12 });

const c = a.merge(b);

console.log(c);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.js"></script>
```

Comment: That works fine but I'm a little constrained by my existing project structure and would need to use Record for this. Any way of achieving this using Records?

Comment: How you've written your code wouldn't work with a merge because `a` and `c` are non-instantiated factories which would only allow the keys set there as default to be modified. i.e if you made a Record from `a` (`new a()`) it would not allow key `z` as it's not listed in the factory.